# Memory overhead of Case classes in scala

Tags: scala, nlp, type-erasure, micro-optimization

What is the memory overhead of a case class in scala ?

I've implemented some code to hold a lexicon with multiple types of interned tokens for NLP processing. I've got a case class for each token type.

For example, the canonical lemma/stem token is as follows:

```
sealed trait InternedLexAtom extends LexAtom{
    def id      : Int
}
case class Lemma(id: Int) extends InternedLexAtom
```

I'm going to be returning document vectors of these interned tokens, the reason I wrap them in case classes is to be able to add methods to the tokens via [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html). The reason I use this way of adding behaviour to the lexeme's is because I want the lexemes to have different methods based on different contexts.

So I'm hoping the answer will be zero memory overhead due to type erasure. Is this the case ?

I have a suspicion that a single pointer might be packed with the parameters for some of the magic Scala can do :(

**justification**

To put things in perspective. The JVM uses 1.5-2gigs of memory with my lexicon loaded (the lexicon does not use cases classes in it's in-memory representation), and C++ does the same in 500-700 mb of memory. If my codebase keeps scaling it's memory requirements the way it is now I'm not going to be able to do this stuff on my laptop (in-memory)

I'll sidestep the problem by structuring my code differently. For example I can just strip away the case classes in vector representations if I need to. Would be nice if I didn't have to.

**Question Extension.**

Robin and Pedro have addressed the use-case, thank you. In this case I was missing value classes. With those there are no more downsides. **additionally**: I tried my best not to mention C++'s POD concept. But now I must ask :D A c++ POD is just a struct with primitive values. If I wanted to pack more than just one value into value class, how would I achieve this ? I am assuming this would be what I want to do ?

```
class SuperTriple(val underlying: Tuple2[Int,Int]) extends AnyVal {
    def super: underlying._1
    def triple: underlying._2
}
```

I do actually need the above construct, since a `SuperTriple` is what I am using as my vector model symbol :D

The **original question** still remains "what is the overhead of a case class".

Comment: If you have no plans to use a class to pattern match on it, there is no reason to mark it as `case` one. As you mentioned, there are only three requirements for `implicit` class: 
1. They must be defined inside of another `trait/class/object`.
2. They may only take one non-implicit argument in their constructor.
3. There may not be any method, member or object in scope with the same name as the implicit class.

Comment: That is a good point, I don't yet know if I need to pattern match. So, are you indirectly implying that regular classes are zero overhead ?

Comment: Case classes gives a lot more than just pattern match: equals, hashCode and in this instance exhaustivity check.

Comment: I think you are mixing implicit classes with value classes: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html.

Comment: If you put a value class object (or a primitive like an int for that matter) into a data structure like a Map or a Vector, it will still get boxed. So there is some significant overhead compared to working with unboxed integers. Even if you turn InternedLexAtom into a value class, a Map[String, InternedLexAtom] will have the overhead of one object per map entry.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.10 you can use [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). (In older versions of Scala, for something with zero overhead for just one member, you need to use *unboxed tagged types.*)

Comment: See also/first: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html . Out of curiosity, where does the term "unboxed tagged type" come from? This is the first time I encounter it in the context of Scala.